# Performance Monitor of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, performance

Is there a way/tool that could basically report what ArcMap 10.2 is doing?

I can't really explain it, so I will show you what I mean. Now mind you it doesn't have to be exactly like this.

```
ARCMAP Report
Query Basemap (150ms)
Draw Basemap (300ms)
Query Layer1 (100ms)
Draw Layer1 (200ms)
Query Layer2 (50ms)
Draw Layer2 (3000ms)
```

The point of this would show me that Layer2 is taking 3 seconds to draw, so maybe I could change the symbolism to make it faster.